# How is the merge function calling the merge_sort function?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

```
def merge_sort(items):
  if len(items) <= 1:
    return items

  middle_index = len(items) // 2
  left_split = items[:middle_index]
  right_split = items[middle_index:]

  left_sorted = merge_sort(left_split)
  right_sorted = merge_sort(right_split)

  return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)

def merge(left, right):
  result = []

  while (left and right):
    if left[0] < right[0]:
      result.append(left[0])
      left.pop(0)
    else:
      result.append(right[0])
      right.pop(0)

  if left:
    result += left
  if right:
    result += right

  return result

unordered_list1 = [356, 746, 264, 569, 949, 895, 125, 455]

ordered_list1 = merge_sort(unordered_list1)
```

I understood when the function `merge_sort()` is called the first time it calls itself recursively until only single elements are left and then while returning will again call `merge()` function which will return an ordered sublist but then how does the function merge_sort() calls itself to move on the next element? I tried visualizing the code but get stuck when `return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)` statement again goes onto run `merge_sort()`.

Can anyone please explain how `return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)` again calls `merge_sort()` after is returned an ordered sublist the first time.

Comment: The magic happens when it goes all the way to the last element and the function always returns a sorted array. This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSceec-wEyw

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please explain how return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted) again calls merge_sort() after is returned an ordered sublist the first time.

Because a prior instance of a to call merge_sort() is still on the stack. Using indentation to show nesting of calls, for a simple example of 4 elements:

```
ordered_list = call merge_sort(items{0 .. 3})
    left_sorted  = call merge_sort(left_split = items{0..2})
        left_sorted  = call merge_sort(left_split  = items{0}) // base case
        right_sorted = call merge_sort(right_split = items{1}) // base case
        return merge(left_sorted, right sorted)
    right_sorted = call merge_sort (right_split = items{2..3})
        left_sorted  = call merge_sort(left_split  = items{2}) // base case
        right_sorted = call merge_sort(right_split = items{3}) // base case
        return merge(left_sorted, right sorted)
    return merge(left_sorted, right sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please explain how return `merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)` again calls `merge_sort()` after is returned an ordered sublist the first time.

`merge` does not call `merge_sort()`, it merges the two sorted sublists into a sorted list.

Only `merge_sort()` calls itself recursively, splitting its list argument into left and right parts until it is reduced to a single element. Each set of recursive calls is followed by a merge phase where the sorted sublists are merged into a sorted sublist returned to its caller...